# Angular, subscribe and Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

Has anyone an idea, why the following code not works?

This should get the first part of data (working fine)
while I have a 'nextPage' in the last result it should get the next data.

Have I overlooked something? Or is my understanding about observables and/or subscribe wrong?

```
getData(): void {
    // saving the searchString
    window.localStorage.setItem('searchString', this.searchString);
    // Initialize items
    this.results = [];
    if (this.searchString) {
      this.cse.getData(this.searchString, appKey, 0)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log('Data found: ', data);
          this.next = data.queries.nextPage[0];
          console.log('Next Page: ', this.next);
          this.results = this.results.concat(data.items);
          console.log('Results: ' ,this.results);
          console.log('StartIndex is: ', this.next.startIndex); <== This is the last message, I can see

          },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
          return;
        });
        console.log('reach this code?...') <== I cant see this on Console
    }

    console.log('StartIndex is: ', this.next.startIndex);
    while (!(this.next.startIndex === undefined)) {
      this.cse.getData(this.next.searchTerms, this.next.cx, this.next.startIndex)
        .subscribe( data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.results = this.results.concat(data.items);
          this.next = data.queries.nextpage;
        }, error =>{
              console.log(error);
              return;
      })
    }

}
```

Now I am one step further. My problem are observables and the asynchronous work in angular.
Let me describe my use case at first. I working on a little application, that collects data from different sources and display them. For this I use the Google programmable search engine JSON API. The results are pageble, each page contains 10 results maximum. For loading the next results I have to call the JSON API again. Three parameters are in the next page section from further result. I need only one of them really, the others are the same as before.

Here is my new code:

```
async getData() {
// saving the searchString
if (!this.searchString) {
  return;
} else {
  this.saveResults(); // Sichern des Standes
  // preparing the call parameters
  let start = 1;
  let next = false;
  do {
    console.log('start loop');
     this.cse.getData(this.searchString,
      appKey,
      start)
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Data found: ', data);
        // var loop: LoopParams = new LoopParams();
        console.log(data.queries.nextPage);
        next = (data.queries.nextPage !== undefined);
        if (next) { start = data.queries.nextPage[0].startIndex; }
        data.items.map(resp => {
          this.createItem(resp);
        });
      });
    console.log('Next/start: ' + next + '/' + start);
  } while (next) ;
  console.log('loops finished');
}
}
```

And this is the output in my console:

```
    start loop
candidate-search.component.ts:112 Next/start (outside): false/1
candidate-search.component.ts:114 loops finished
candidate-search.component.ts:101 Data found:  {kind: "customsearch#search", url: {…}, queries: {…}, context: {…}, searchInformation: {…}, …}
candidate-search.component.ts:103 [{…}]
candidate-search.component.ts:106 next:  true
candidate-search.component.ts:107 start:  11
```

My first thought was: Why do I actually need observables for this use case? There will be no new data, not in the next 100 years :-)
So at first, I changed my service to return a Promise, and not a Observable. Here is the code of my service:

```
    export class CseService {

    query: string;
    nextPage: any;
    exactTerm: string;
    excludeTerm: string;

    urlStr = '';
  result: any;



  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }


     getData(q: string,
             cx: string,
             start: number) {

      alert('Start: ' + start); // the alert is to stopping loops, when required

      if (q) {
        let url = this.buildUrl() + '&cx=' + cx;
        if (start > 10) {
          url = url + '&start=' + start;
        }
        url = url + '&q=' + q;

        this.result = this.http.get(url)
          .pipe(delay(1000))
          .toPromise();
        return this.result;

      }
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:indent
    private buildUrl(): string {
    return baseUrl + '?key=' + key;
  }
}
```

Doesn't help. It trys to loop, before 'start' and 'next are set.

**Update: 10.06.21 09:17**

I found the solution. Two little words: async and await.
I marked the function with async and then the call of the service (and all working with '.then()' with await and: what wonder, it works now.
I'm so happy and I have learned a lot in the last days.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz? BTW I believe that while loop is to check whether the first subscription is complete or not, right? If so, it is better to move the second subscription inside the first one.

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm asking the wrong question. Let me describe, what I'm trying to do. I work with the JSON API of Googles customer search engine. the results are pageble, I always get 10 results maximum. One part of the results is a dateset called 'queries.nextpage' As long 'data.queries.nextpage is defined I need to start a new query. The idea was, putting the queries in a loop until the result (data) does not contain a queries.nextpage. But I cant get this information outside of the  subscribe. This is the problem here.

Comment: In that case, your current logic won't work. Put the service call inside a function and call it recursively inside the subscription (if nextpage exist).

Comment: done! That was one of my trials in the last couple of days. The problem is the same: nextpage and startindex are in the results. An I can't access them for contruction a loop.